# Does wp_login hook fire on user registration?

Tags: hooks, users, login, user-registration

My site is set to immediately login a user after they register.  I'm writing a plug-in which needs to fire wherever a user logs in.

If I order the wp_login hook, will this fire at user registration (which includes logging in)?  Unfortunately the ref pages don't say anything specifically about this:  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_login/

I know I can use the registration hook but prefer to avoid using extra how if I can help it.  Is wp_login won't fire in above case, would wp_authenticate fire?

Answer (score 0):

no, new user registration wont fire the `wp_login` by default. the only action hook that fire for new user registration is `user_register`.

But since you are auto logging user after registration, you should provide on how you achived this, if you are using a plugin for auto login, this depends if they call `do_action('wp_logn', .........)`

if you manually doing it on `functions.php` via `user_register` hook, then execute the `do_action('wp_logn', .........)`